# Write a query to display unique student ID who joined in the month of June. Sort the result in ascending order

Tags: sql, date, where-clause, rdbms

this is what I tried-

```
select distinct studid 
from registration 
where to_char(doj,'MM')='june'
order by studid;
```

but I did not get the desired results.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Oracle? `to_char()` isn't a MySQL function. Don't include unreated tags.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO_CHAR() with MM parameter will give you 06, instead of JUNE. You may try below query instead -

```
select distinct studid 
from registration 
where to_char(doj,'MM')='06'
order by studid;
```

Rather than using TO_CHAR, You should use oracle specific function EXTRACT -

```
select distinct studid 
from registration 
where extract(month from doj) = 6
order by studid;
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are running Oracle, as the use of `to_char()` suggests.

If you want students that joined in june of a given year, say 2019, then I would recommend to check `doj` against a half-open interval (this is more efficient than applying a date function on the column):

```
select distinct studid
from registration
where doj >= date '2019-06-01' and doj < date '2019-07-01'
order by studid
```

On the other hand, if you want sudents that joined in any month of june:

```
select distinct studid
from registration
where extract(month from doj) = 6
order by studid
```